# Find the minimum value in each column with their index

Tags: pandas, aggregation, minimum

I wonder if there is any method that I can use to get the minimum value in each column with its index id without using the aggregate method (df.agg(['min','idmin']).T) for this code?!!

```
dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), index=dates, columns=list('ABCD'))
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Please provide some example.

Comment: I already provide all the code to get the output!

Comment: `(df.agg(['min','idmin']).T) ` doesn't work?

Comment: what version of Pandas you are using?!

Comment: 0.20? I get a ValueError.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Construct a DataFrame from scratch:

```
pd.DataFrame({'min': df.min(), 'idxmin': df.idxmin()})

       min     idxmin
A -1.106929 2013-01-03
B -0.642583 2013-01-06
C -1.350638 2013-01-04
D -0.213750 2013-01-06
```

or concat the two Series:

```
pd.concat((df.min(), df.idxmin()), axis=1).rename(columns={0: 'min', 1: 'idxmin'})
Out: 
        min     idxmin
A -1.106929 2013-01-03
B -0.642583 2013-01-06
C -1.350638 2013-01-04
D -0.213750 2013-01-06
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), index=dates, columns=list('ABCD'))

def minVal(x):
    return pd.Series(index=['min','idx'],data=[x.min(),x.idxmin()])

x = df.apply(minVal)

print(x)

          A                 B                      C                   D
min -0.743023394642       -1.05144770539       -2.1311363065        -1.02142276427
idx 2013-01-05 00:00:00   2013-01-04 00:00:00  2013-01-03 00:00:00  2013-01-06 00:00:00
```

You could also do a Transpose of x to get the gist of Data.

```
print(x.T)

      min            idx
A  -0.657701  2013-01-05 00:00:00
B   -1.37038  2013-01-03 00:00:00
C   -1.93103  2013-01-03 00:00:00
D   -1.49314  2013-01-05 00:00:00
```